# How do I get a distinct count of column groups per row?

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to get a count of providers and the items they sell based on a service type ID. I want to make a temp table with a count of items in each group of service types per provider, but I am only getting the total count of each group for the whole table. here is what I have so far:

```
SELECT dme_branches.provider_id, 
countDME= (select count(service_type_id) from dme_items where service_type_id
IN(1,2,3,5,6,11,12,13,14,15,19,20,21,22,24,25,29,31)), 

countOP=(select count(service_type_id) from dme_items where service_type_id IN (4,23)),

countHH=(select count(service_type_id) from dme_items where service_type_id IN (7,17,26,27)),

countDI=(select count(service_type_id) from dme_items where service_type_id IN (8,18,28)),

countTT=(select count(service_type_id) from dme_items where service_type_id IN (9,10)),

countIV=(select count(service_type_id) from dme_items where service_type_id IN (16)) 

INTO #branchClassification 
FROM dme_branches
JOIN dme_items ON dme_items.provider_id=dme_branches.provider_id
group by dme_branches.provider_id
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not using you aggregates functions correctly. Every one of your aggregated columns is a subquery over the whole table, with no condition on how to relate it to the current row, so that's the reason you get the same results. 
Try this instead:

```
SELECT  dme_branches.provider_id, 
        countDME = SUM(CASE 
                            WHEN service_type_id IN (1,2,3,5,6,11,12,13,14,15,19,20,21,22,24,25,29,31)
                            THEN 1
                            ELSE 0 
                        END),
        countOP = SUM(CASE WHEN service_type_id IN (4,23) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
        countHH = SUM(CASE WHEN service_type_id IN (7,17,26,27) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
        countDI = SUM(CASE WHEN service_type_id IN (8,18,28) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
        countTT = SUM(CASE WHEN service_type_id IN (9,10) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
        countIV = SUM(CASE WHEN service_type_id = 16 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
INTO #branchClassification 
FROM dme_branches b
INNER JOIN dme_items i
    ON i.provider_id = b.provider_id
GROUP BY b.provider_id
```